# Can you close empty gaps between array indices in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indices

I have an algorithm where some array will be given a new index, but the new index is **not** sequential. For the sake of time, just assume the new index is given to the array at random. Let's say I have this array:

```js
const arr = [];
arr[5] = 'a'
arr[2] = 'b'
arr[9] = 'c'
arr[0] = 'd'
```

If I `console.log` this array to the output window, I get this:

```js
['d', empty, 'b', empty × 2, 'a', empty × 3, 'c']
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to close/remove those empty gaps between values so the array entries are sorted by their actual index, so I can get this output:

```js
['d', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

Is there a short and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Array.prototype.filter` and filter out undefined values. You can take a shortcut by coercing them into boolean using the `!!` operator:

```
arr.filter(x => !!x);
```

This check is loose/dirty because anything falsy will be coerced to false, e.g. the numeric `0`. If you *really* want to be strict and only filter out `undefined`, then you need a stricter predicate:

```
array.filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined');
```

```js
const arr = [];
arr[5] = 'a';
arr[2] = 'b';
arr[9] = 'c';
arr[0] = 'd';

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.filter(x => !!x));
console.log(arr.filter(x => typeof x !== 'undefined'));
```

Comment: Ah I see, I'm still pretty new I forgot about `filter`. Thank you for this, I'll accept this answer when the site lets me.

Comment: This works for logging the array but I'd note that the new filtered array will have the element indices converted back to the standard sequential scheme (0,1,2,3).

Comment: @CRice I don't think I understand you: the filtered array will have length of 4 so the indices will be 0,1,2,3, with the order of entries being preserved as-is: 0: d, 1: b, 2: a, 3: c

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it, the new array will be just as you said. I just wanted to highlight the that the items in each array have different indices: in the original `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` respectively have indices `5`, `2`, `9`, and `0`, but in the new one they change to respectively `2`, `1`, `3` and `0`. I'm not sure what use case requires OP to use non-sequential indices so I don't know if that will affect it.

Comment: @Terry I just have one concern though; this would become pretty slow if you have really large gaps between values, right? If I'm not mistaken, the `filter` function works iteratively so if you had an array like this: `['a', empty x 9999999, 'b']` and I wanted to close that gap, would this become a bad solution? And if so, would there be a better solution for this case?

Comment: I think for use cases like that, you might not want to start populating an empty array with arbitrary indices. Use either an object/dictionary or a `Map` instead, and you can store index-value pairs as objects.

Answer (score 0):

simply use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method
to "clean up" your array, wthiut creating a new one.

need to use reverse index progression

```js
const arr = [];
arr[5] = 'a';
arr[2] = 'b';
arr[9] = 'c';
arr[0] = 'd';

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

for (let i=arr.length; i-- > 0;) 
  {
  if (arr[i]===undefined) arr.splice(i,1);
  }
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```